# Incorrect grammar on StackApps registration page sidebar

Tags: bug, status-completed, grammar, stackapps

The sidebar of the StackApps [registration page](https://stackapps.com/apps/oauth/register) states:

> You'll also receive parameters for authentication users via OAuth 2.0.

I believe this should read:

> You'll also receive parameters for **authenticating** users via OAuth 2.0.

Comment: To the close voter: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/218299/should-we-close-bug-reports-that-are-tagged-status-completed for the reason this should not need to go through the tedious close-vote process.