# Missing space in list on help message

Tags: bug, status-completed, stackegg

> [image: Your Site's answers, users, andquality stats are dangerously low.]

It needs a space after "and".

Comment: Wow, are people really voting to close a "status-completed" question as "can no longer be reproduced". I'm not sure whether to laugh or cry....

Comment: @James Why? It's common practice

Comment: It is? I thought if a problem couldn't be reproduced it was labelled as such, but if it *is* reproduced and *fixed* then it's labelled status-completed. Labeling something "not a problem" because it has been resolved seems quite illogical.

Comment: I agree with you @James. I started a bounty on [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/218299/should-we-close-bug-reports-that-are-tagged-status-completed) so we can all re-look how we're handling these.

Comment: @James Since this is about stackegg though, this question should be closed since Stackegg was a very temporary part of SE.

Comment: @Roombatron5000 - Actually, I can agree with that. As there is a solid and specific reason to close even though it's status-completed. But in other cases, there is no point in advancing from "status-completed" as that is a solid enough "final" or "completion" to the question itself, without needing additional.My full take: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/252990/230506

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thisissueisfixedasoflast build.